# Is there a way to insert a record in SQL server if it does not match the latest version of the record based on three of the columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following table named `UserAttributes`:

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+
| Id | UserId | AttrName | AttrValue |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+
|  4 |      1 | FavFood  | Apples    |
|  3 |      2 | FavFood  | Burgers   |
|  2 |      1 | FavShape | Circle    |
|  1 |      1 | FavFood  | Chicken   |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to insert a new record in this table if the latest version of a particular attribute for a user has a value that does not match the latest.

What I mean by the latest is, for example, if I was to do:
`SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [UserAttributes] WHERE [UserId] = 1 AND [AttrName] = 'FavFood' ORDER BY [Id] DESC`

I will be able to see that user ID 1's current favorite food is "Apples".

Is there a query safe for concurrency that will only insert a new favorite food if it doesn't match the current favorite food for this user?

I tried using the `MERGE` query with a `HOLDLOCK`, but the problem is that `WHEN MATCHED`/`WHEN NOT MATCHED`, and that works if I never want to insert a new record after a user has previously set their favorite food (in this example) to the new value. However, it does not consider that a user might switch to a new favorite food, then subsequently change back to their old favorite food. I would like to maintain all the changes as a historical record.

In the data set above, I would like to insert a new record if the user ID 1's new favorite food is "Burgers", but I do not want to insert a record if their new favorite food is "Apples" (since that is their current favorite food). I would also like to make this operation safe for concurrency.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I should probably also mention that when I split this operation into two queries (ie: first select their current favorite food, then do an insert query only if there is a new food detected) it works under normal conditions. However, we are observing race conditions (and therefore duplicates) since (as you may have guessed) the data set above is simply an example and there are many threads operating on this table at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit ugly, but to do it in one command, you could insert the user's (new) favorite food but filter with an [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of their current values.

e.g., (assuming the user's new data is in @UserID, @FavFood

```
; WITH LatestFavFood AS
    (SELECT TOP(1) UserID, AttrName, AttrValue 
      FROM  [UserAttributes] 
      WHERE [UserId] = @UserID AND [AttrName] = 'FavFood' 
      ORDER BY [Id] DESC
     )
INSERT INTO UserAttributes (UserID, AttrName, AttrValue)
    SELECT  @UserID, 'FavFood', @FavFood
  EXCEPT
    SELECT  UserID, AttrName, AttrValue
    FROM    LatestFavFood
```

Here's a [DB_Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab98830bdcacfdfed735b6cdde5c4775) with three runs.

EDIT: I have changed the above to assume varchar types for AttrName rather than nvarchar. The fiddle has a mixture. Would be good to ensure you get them correct (especially food as it may have special characters).

Comment: This is awesome! I can do some testing, but off the top of your head, do you know if this is susceptible to race conditions? If so, is there a way to add a lock around it? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Edge cases for race conditions are not my speciality unfortunately. As it's a single command I believe it runs atomically. But if the same user, in different sessions, says (at exactly the same time) that they have different foods, then I don't know (logically) how to tell which one will 'win'.

Comment: Sorry - my previous comment was very terse! If anyone has any insight into this, I'd actually be fascinated if this _could_ run into race condition issues other than the above. The only issue I can foresee is more a locking issue if there are massive numbers of rows with poor indexing, and the SELECT to get the latest favorite food needs a clustered index scan and causes poor performance and possible table locks.

Comment: No worries, I really didn't feel like it came off that way! I really like your solution and (to your point) maybe someone else will be able to provide some extra detail around that.